# How to find whether at least one column satisfies a certain condition, with NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe with multiple columns: I need to identify those rows in which there is at least one outlier among some of the columns, but I do not know how to deal with NAs.

An example of dataframe (different from mine):

```
# X   atq   ME.BE.crsp     X2
# 1    10   0.5             4
# NA    2    1.3            5 
# 3     NA    5             2 
# NA    NA    NA            NA 
# 2     4     NA            3
```

I'm doing the following:

```
data = data %>%
 mutate(outlier= as.numeric(atq > quantile(atq, 0.99,na.rm=T)|
                                  atq < quantile(atq, 0.01,na.rm=T)|
                                  ME.BE.crsp > quantile(ME.BE.crsp, 0.99,na.rm = T)|
                                  ME.BE.crsp < quantile(ME.BE.crsp, 0.01,na.rm = T)
                                 ))
```

My expected result is (I'm making up the outliers, the point is about NAs):

```
# X   atq   ME.BE.crsp     X2    outlier
# 1    10   0.5             4      1
# NA    2    1.3            5      0
# 3     NA    5             2      0
# NA    NA    NA            NA     NA
# 2     4     NA            3      1
```

What I get instead is:

```
# X   atq   ME.BE.crsp     X2    outlier
# 1    10   0.5             4      1
# NA    2    1.3            5      0
# 3     NA    5             2      NA
# NA    NA    NA            NA     NA
# 2     4     NA            3      NA
```

So, it seems that as soon as the as.numeric finds an NA either in data$atq or in data$ME.BE.crsp, it just gives NA to data$outlier, while I would like it to consider the non NA value and assign 0 or 1 based on that one. 
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I thiink the `NA` comparison is the issue `NA > 5#
[1] NA`. You can add an expression `!is.na(atq) &`, similarly `!is.na(ME.BE.crsp) &`

Comment: But even if the answer to NA > 5 is NA, the answer to as.numeric(NA | TRUE) should be what? I thought it should be TRUE and thus 1, but apparently it is not. How can I make it give the result of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both'atq' and 'ME.BE.crsp' are `NA` and it should return `NA`, then use a condition with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    mutate(outlier= case_when(is.na(atq)  & is.na(ME.BE.crsp) ~ 
         NA_real_, 
        TRUE ~ as.numeric((atq > quantile(atq, 0.99,na.rm=TRUE)) & 
                                  !is.na(atq)|
                               (atq < quantile(atq, 0.01,na.rm=T)) & !is.na(atq)|
                               (ME.BE.crsp > quantile(ME.BE.crsp, 0.99,na.rm = T)) & 
                                        !is.na(ME.BE.crsp)|
                               (ME.BE.crsp < quantile(ME.BE.crsp, 0.01,na.rm = T)) & 
                                        !is.na(ME.BE.crsp)
                              )))
```

Comment: It works! Thanks :) Could you explain what is the function of NA_real_ and TRUE  ~?

Comment: @Esperanta  If you check the `?NA` `There are also constants NA_integer_, NA_real_, NA_complex_ and NA_character_ of the other atomic vector types which support missing values: all of these are reserved words in the R language.`. `case_when` is very particular about type matching.  As the second expresssion `TRUE ~ ` returns a numeric/double, we need an `NA` with the matching one